# SBT incremental compilation with WebJars inside Docker

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, sbt, webjars

I am working on Play! application with Angular 2 and webjars dependencies. 
SBT play plugin and typescript plugin. I use incremental compilation, but it takes great amount of time on each recompilation. I set "sbt-optimizer" to check which tasks are longest one. And i see that on each recompilation WebJars are taking almost all the recompile time. I can't imagine why he needs to do something with static files after first compilation. But even if i change scala file or twirl template, it does not matter again all webjars.

UPD:
If i run on machine without Docker then speed is normal - recompile take few seconds.
Inside Docker - 200sec+.

Compilation messages without docker - 2s, inside docker - 13s. 
Operations on screen without docker 10-300ms inside docker 500-60000ms.

UPD:
Adding my docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8

ENV SCALA_VERSION=2.12.1
ENV SBT_VERSION=0.13.13
ENV NODEJS_VERSION=6.10.0

# Install sbt
RUN cd /tmp && \
wget https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/$SBT_VERSION/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip && \
unzip sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip -d /usr/local && \
rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.zip

#install nodejs for web jars
RUN cd /tmp && \
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODEJS_VERSION/node-v$NODEJS_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz && \
tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xJf node-v$NODEJS_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz &&
rm node-v$NODEJS_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz
```

Here is printout from optimizer:
[image]

May be i missed something, or someone had such problems, why SBT do that each time, and how can i prevent this?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like problem because i run it inside Docker container, previously with Vagrant had problems with live refresh. And now inside Docker container very slow reload.
Versions:
SBT 0.13.13
Play 2.5.12

Comment: If i run without docker then reload takes few seconds. And inside Docker container it takes 200sec. Memory and CPU usage looks pretty similar on both runs.
But time for same operations like on screen 10-300ms while in docker 500-60000ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a mounted volume on Docker for Mac, you're probably hitting [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/77) with performance of mounted volumes.

Comment: Very big Thanks!!! I had thought that problem could be with IO operations. Did not go deeply through it, but looks like you are right.